# How to provide multiple implementations for a class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-ioc

We are using some geocoding to encode a few entries. Depending on some conditions we would like to switch from an implementation to another (different provider).

Current service provider declaration:

```
// some skipped and irrelevant imports

class GeocoderServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton(GoogleMaps::class, function($app) {
            $adapter = $app->make(Client::class);
            $regionBiaising = 'US';
            $apiKey = $app['config']->get('services.googleGeocoding.apiKey');
            return new GoogleMaps($adapter, $regionBiaising, $apiKey);
        });

        $this->app->singleton(Geocoder::class, function($app) {
            $provider = $app->make(GoogleMaps::class);
            return new StatefulGeocoder($provider, 'en');
        });
    }

}
```

Current injection:

```
class SomeClientClass {

    /**
     * @var Geocoder
     */
    private $geocoder;

    public function __construct(Geocoder $geocoder) {
        $this->_geocoder = $geocoder;
    }

    // some code doing useful things

}
```

**The target is to achieve something like this:**

```
class SomeClientClass {

    /**
     * @var Geocoder
     */
    private $geocoder;

    public function __construct(Geocoder $geocoder, Whatever $alternativeGeocoder) {
        $this->_geocoder = ($condition) ? $geocoder : $alternativeGeocoder;
    }

    // some code doing useful things

}
```

I have tried to hack my way through it by making a fake subclass for my alternative `Geocoder`, unfortunately `Geocoder\StatefulGeocoder` is `final`. So this is not a solution.

**EDIT**

`Geocoder` seems to support multiple provider, so this should fix it. I leave the question open for I think a general answer would be relevant.

Comment: would contextual bindings help? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#contextual-binding

Comment: Definitely something I didn't know, so it ranks as pretty neat cool ;) But not fitting the example since I would like to provide two instances to the same class.